# Счетчик не передает значение в функцию

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой код:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= some.length; i++) {
  block1[i].onmouseenter = function() {
    block2[i].classList.toggle('active_game');
  }
}
```

`block2` не получает `i`

Вот что я планировал:

```
block1[0].onmouseenter = function() {
  block2[0].classList.toggle('active_game');
}
block1[1].onmouseenter = function() {
  block2[1].classList.toggle('active_game');
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу решить данную проблему. Желательно на native js.

Comment: html код в студию

Comment: Замените `var` на `let`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все обработчики в вашем коде ссылаются на одну переменную `i`. 
Можно заменить `var` на `let` или попробовать такой вариант:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= some.length; i++) {
  createHandler(i);
}

function createHandler(id) {
  block1[id].onmouseenter = function(){
      block2[id].classList.toggle('active_game');
  }
}
```

Comment: Заменил в for var на let и всё заработало. Больше вам спасибо